# Why does using dtrunc give me error message?

Tags: r, distribution, beta

I want to  truncate beta distribution that is  the value of the beta distribution in [0,0.2] is zero. I used "dtrunc" as follows:

I encountered the following error message:

> "Error in g(x, ...) : argument "shape1" is missing, with no default"

Could yo please let me know what is happening?

```
p <-seq(0,1,length=1000)
pdf <- dtrunc(p, spec="beta", a = 0, b = 0.2,log=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `truncdist` package (you should always specify when you're using non-base resources, as there could be a `dtrunc()` function in more than one non-base package): you need to use `shape1` and `shape2` as the names of the shape parameters, not `a` and `b`

```
pdf <- dtrunc(p, spec="beta", shape1 = 0, shape2 = 0.2,log=FALSE)
```

This is line with the base R function `dbeta` (which *does* use `a` and `b` in the *Details* section, but it's explicit:

> The Beta distribution with parameters ‘shape1’ = a and ‘shape2’ =
>        b has density
>
> ```
>           Gamma(a+b)/(Gamma(a)Gamma(b))x^(a-1)(1-x)^(b-1)
> ```